# Why do I get different results in the draining tank problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

[This is a sketch of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmslY.png)We have to do a small mathematical paper for our school in which we wanted to describe the water that flows out of the cylinder with a differential equation. We also wanted to test the accuracy of this equation. But our experiment took only half as long as the equation suggested. We think it would make sense if the real life example would take longer because of friction and some other factors but not shorter.

(edit:)

$$\frac {\Delta V}{\Delta t} = A * \frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= aw-av(t) $$

The different variables are displayed in the image in the beginning.

However, for this situation we set w to zero because the water only leaves the cylinder.

We can therefore write it as:

$$\frac {\Delta V}{\Delta t} = A * \frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= -av(t) $$

The velocity is described as @JaapScherphuis said in [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law).

We can steal the velocity from Torricelli's law and implement it into the equation:
$$ v = \sqrt {2gh(t)} $$
$$\frac {\Delta V}{\Delta t} = A * \frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= -a\sqrt {2gh(t)}  $$

Now we need to rearrange the terms and integrate it:

$$\frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= -\frac aA\sqrt {2gh(t)}  $$

$$\frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= -\frac aA\sqrt{2g}\sqrt {h(t)}  $$
$$\frac {\Delta h}{\Delta t}= c_1\sqrt {h(t)}  $$
$$\frac {\Delta h}{\sqrt {h(t)}}= c_1\Delta t  $$
$$\int\frac {\Delta h}{\sqrt {h(t)}}= \int c_1\Delta t  $$
$$\int\frac {\Delta h}{\sqrt {h(t)}}= \int c_1\Delta t  $$
$$ 2 *{\sqrt {h(t)}}= c_1t + c$$
$$ h(t)= \left( \frac {c_1t + c}2 \right)^2$$

We know that $h(0)=h_0$ as $h_0$ is the starting height:

$$ h(0)= \left( \frac {c_1*0 + c}2 \right)^2 = h_0$$

$$ \left( \frac c2 \right)^2 = h_0$$
$$ \frac c2 = \sqrt {h_0}$$
$$c = 2*\sqrt {h_0}$$

We can now substitute c and $c_1$ back into the equation:

$$ h(t)= \left( \frac {-\frac aA\sqrt{2g}*t + 2*\sqrt {h_0}}2 \right)^2$$

Which can be rearranged to the following equation:

(edit end)

Dif equation: $$ h(t) = \left(\sqrt h_0 - \frac aA * \sqrt {2g} * \frac t2\right)^2 $$

Starting height: $h_0$ was equal to $0.45m$

Crosssection of the exit: $a$ was equal to $0.000079m^2$ with a radius of $0.005m$

Crossection of the cylinder: $A$ was equal to $0.0028m^2$ with a radius of $0.03m$

With some transformation we solved this equation for the time it should have taken to completely empty the cylinder. This yielded the following formula:

$$t=2\left( \frac {\sqrt {h_0} * A} {a * \sqrt {2*g}}\right)$$

Plugging the numbers in yields:

$$t=2\left( \frac {\sqrt {0.45m} * 0.0028m^2} {0.000079m^2 * \sqrt {2*9.81\frac m{s^2}}}\right) \approx 10.74s $$

The average time that the experiment resulted in however was only about $6.724s$ with a standard deviation of approximately $0.1710s$

We are at the end of our wits and do not know how to proceed nor how to describe this difference in time.
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: This belongs on physics.se.  You should explain how you got the first equation.  You are presumably computing the pressure at the bottom of the tank and using that to get a flow velocity, but why are the constants what they are?

Comment: One obvious thing to test is the effect of experimental uncertainties. For instance your final result is proportional to the radius-squared of the hole, so a 10% uncertainty in the hole radius translates to a 20% uncertainty in the time.

Comment: Btw I checked your working and $\approx 10.74$s seems correct. So as semiclassical suggested, it seems other factors may be causing it.

Comment: The formula matches what I've seen elsewhere (e.g. wiki page on [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law#Time_to_empty_a_cylindrical_vessel) ), so it is more of a physics problem than a mathematical one.

Comment: have you accounted for the viscosity of the fluid

Comment: @RossMillikan The constants were taken from the cylinder on which which we performed the experiment. We also thought that this belongs on math.se because we are doing a high school math paper and our teacher approved this topic so we thought it belongs here.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks we will look into it :)

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for the approval :D

Comment: @HenryLee the fluid is water so we thought there shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I was referring to the constants in the equation, especially the $\sqrt{2g}$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yeah it probably is D:

Comment: @RossMillikan ok i will edit it

Comment: @SimonSchulz I have written an answer. I assume this is for school so I won't go too into depth but there are many things that contribute to changes in pressure such as "head loss" and viscosity in reality will always have an effect as well as turbulence in the water caused by the surface being atmospheric and it draining due to gravity

Comment: You suppose the diameter of the hole is $5$ mm. If the diameter of the hole were $6.3$ mm then the result of the calculation would agree with the observations.

Comment: @DavidK the radius of the hole is 5mm and not the diameter. Im not sure if you just mixed them up or not but thanks :)

Comment: Change the word "diameter" to "radius" and the comment then applies. To put it another way, the difference in draining times could be explained by a $20\%$ error in the radius of the hole (since $5$ is about $20\%$ less than $6.3$).

Answer (score 1):

The pressure of a static fluid at a depth of $h$, gravitational strength $g$ and density $\rho$ is:
$$p=\rho gh+p_{atm}$$
If you have a hole in the bottom of a container and assume the flow to be laminar then the flow $Q$ is given by Poiseuille's equation which can be derived using shear forces:
$$Q=\frac{\pi d^4\Delta p}{128\mu\Delta x}\tag{1}$$
Although this is applied to pipes normally of length $\Delta x$ and allows for pressure loss in this situation. Your best bet might be to use bernoulli's equation and consider the change in vertical displacement to be negligible (since it is passing just through a hole). This will give you:
$$p_1+\frac12\rho v_1^2=p_2+\frac12\rho v_2^2\tag{2}$$
Now in your situation the fluid can be assumed to be initially stationary so $v_1=0$ now we get:
$$\frac12\rho v_2^2=p_1-p_2$$
and we can assume that it is flowing into air so the pressure would just be $p_{atm}$ which gives us the expression:
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{2(\rho gh)}{\rho}}\tag{3}$$
now the flow rate:
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=av\tag{4}$$
and we know that the volume:
$$V=Ah\Rightarrow\frac{dV}{dt}=A\frac{dh}{dt}\tag{5}$$
since the cross sectional area is constant for a cylinder. Now combine the two equations:
$$A\frac{dh}{dt}=-a\sqrt{\frac{2(\rho gh)}{\rho}}\tag{6}$$
Now you have an equation for the change in height in terms of the height. Solving the differential equation and putting in initial conditions should give you an equation. Bare in mind that what is actually happening cannot even be described using Poiseuille's equation because the size of the hole and the fact it could be uneven contributes to a non-laminar flow which is much harder to model. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SimonSchulz basically to sum it up in theory it follows Torrecelli's law but this is actually just based on Bernoulli's principle which in its simple form assumes incompressible, laminar flow (low mach number) and in this case we are not accounting for any losses due to the hole itself

Comment: My comment was based on same working as you have here and I had got $\approx 10.7$, similar to OP, nowhere close to actual result he is seeing and so reasons seem to be other factor(s).